# Parsing JSON date (that includes week number) in python

Tags: python, json, date, github, python-requests

I'm importing the number of weekly commits using the Github API and the following code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/d3/d3/stats/commit_activity')
raw = r.text
results = json.loads(raw)
df = pd.DataFrame(results)

print df.sort(['total','week'], ascending=False)
```

However, the 'week' column data shows up, for example, like this:

0     1450569600

1     1451174400

How can I convert this column into a readable date? The value includes both the week number (e.g. 0) and the "1450569600" information.

Thanks!

Comment: what does `1450569600` represent ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're getting the [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) ( 1450569600 GMT: Sun, 20 Dec 2015 00:00:00 GMT. Use datetime module to convert with [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

According to the api documentation, the large integer is a unix timestamp.  You can convert that to a datetime object with `datetime.fromtimestamp`. For example:

```
import datetime
timestamp = "1450569600"
date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(timestamp))
date.strptime()
```

With that you now have a standard datetime.datetime value. You can use `strftime` to format that as a string if you wish:

```
print(date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
-> 2015-12-19 18:00:00
```